# How to draw a line beet wen two points in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, geometry

I have an animations with jQuery which looks like that:

```
$(function() {

var elems = $('div.icon').not('#icon-0');

var increase = Math.PI * 2 / elems.length,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    angle = 0,
    radius = 200;

var center_top = ($("#slider-1").outerHeight() - $("#icon-0").outerHeight())/2,
    center_left = ($("#slider-1").outerWidth() - $("#icon-0").outerWidth())/2;


$('.icon').css({
    'top': center_top + 'px',
    'left': center_left + 'px'
});

$(elems).css('opacity', '0').each(function(i) {
    elem = elems[i];

    x = radius * Math.cos(angle) + center_left;
    y = radius * Math.sin(angle) + center_top;

    $(elem).delay(400*i).animate({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': x + 'px',
        'top': y + 'px',
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 1000);

    angle += increase;

});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6pYR/

How do I write the line between the circle in the center and each of the outer circles?

I tried with the canvas and getting center coordinates via offset and some easy math, but canvas wouldn't do it properly or I just can't do that.

I'd appreciate any help from you guys.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking into mind that you do not want to use canvas (or is not feasible) made ​​a solution using css3 transform ...

follows the solution

in this JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/d6pYR/2/

you need to create more one css class to make a line

```
.line {
     border-top: 1px solid black;
     position: absolute;
     height: 1px;
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform-origin: left;
     transform-origin: left;
}
```

to create a element you can create in loop

```
    var line = $("<div class='line'></div>");
    slider.append(line);
    line.css("width", 0);        

    line.css("top", center_top + ( $(this).height() / 2 ) );
    line.css("left", center_left + ( $(this).width() / 2 ) );
    line.css("transform", "rotateZ(" + angle + "rad)");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Had the same idea but couln'd come into a solution. Cheers!